# Adding elements to a List is too slow

Tags: java, loops

I have this loop:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 for(int x=0; x<citiesNames.size();x++){
            List<Cities> numeroCiudades = citiesRepository.findByCity(citiesNames.get(x));
            numbers.add(numeroCiudades.size());
            //System.out.println(numeroCiudades.size());
        }
```

where citiesNames is a List of String which contains 16584 elements and findByCity a method where I pass a String and it search in the database the correponding entries.
What I want to do is to search the correponding entries of each city, check the number of entries, and add the number of entries to a Integer List. But this loop is too slow, is taking a very long time to show te result. How can I optimize this?

Comment: Is the return type of `citiesNames.get` a `String`?  You may wind up optimizing  `citiesRepository.findByCity`.

Comment: You're declaring the list inside the loop. That doesn't seem right at all.

Comment: I guess it is more your database searching that is slowing down things, rather than the adding to the ArrayList.

Comment: In addition on what has been said, it could make sense to set assign list capacity in advance. On large list resizing (which happens) can provoke significant performance drops. Read on what capacity is and how ArrayList works.

Comment: In addition to @AnisR. 's  comment - try to fetch all the city names in a batch or using pagination if the amount can be significant (100 is significant enough for many usages)

Comment: If that's a JPA repository, consider using a count query instead of taking the `size()` of the result of a regular query.

Comment: Your problem is the number of database accesses, can't you have a single query returning a list of ints for a given list of cities? So you have a single database access

Answer (score 1):

I don't clearly get why you have to "pack" all cities in a List when you could create a function in citiesRepository that returns an int with the number of entries that particular city has. (That would increase performance a lot. Thus, the program would be able to just return a simple int instead of a whole class instantiation) (Supposing you have access to citiesRepository).

In addition, it could make sense to set assign list capacity in advance. On large list resizing can provoke significant performance drops (read more about how ArrayList works [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html))

Answer (score 0):

You could use a parallel stream, assuming `citiesName` is a normal Java collections type:

```
citiesName.parallelStream()
          .map(citiesRepository::findByCity)
          .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Just beware the [pitfalls of the parallel stream](https://dzone.com/articles/think-twice-using-java-8) and how it uses the shared `ForkJoinPool`.

Comment: This still fetches every city from the database. Streams are good for readability, not performance.

Comment: Agree. A batch operation would be preferred, but it's not always feasible (i.e. you don't have control over the DAO or remote API to offer a batch operation). A parallel stream is a step above a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

To optimize this loop, you will have to modify findByCity so that it could maybe process all of it at once. 
If you can't modify findByCity, you can always use parallelism with Streams:

```
    int numbers[] = citiesNames.parallelStream()
            .mapToInt(c -> citiesRepository.findByCity(c).size())
            .toArray();
```